# Icarus compiler setup on docker

Tags: python, docker, compiler-construction, containers, virtual-machine

There is a python and JS application that uses ICARUS compiler to run. To use this application on different devices i need to install the compiler on the devices. Instead i planned to use docker for the purpose. Can somebody tell how can i proceed for this approach.

Created a Dockerfile
Build the Docker Image
Run the Docker Container
Automating process

```
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
import subprocess

class MyHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_created(self, event):
        if event.is_directory:
            return
        print(f'File {event.src_path} has been added. Running the compiler...')
        subprocess.run(["Icaurs", event.src_path])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    path = '/app'  #my application path
    event_handler = MyHandler()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=False)
    observer.start()

    try:
        while True:
            pass
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

Comment: As a side note: `while True: pass` will eat up your CPU.